# Logging in to Parse.com on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, apple-watch

My app requires the user to sign in with a username and password. On the phone this is fine however I would like to add some of the apps features to the Apple Watch. Is it possible to pass a string (username and password) from the iPhone to the watch to sign in. 
Or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: If your already using your phone, why not just sign in there? Two extra steps seems like it's going against Apples foundation of simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you would want to pass username/password FROM the iPhone App to the WatchKit Extension since the Parse login code should be running on the iPhone's side.

However, to answer your question - Yes, it's possible.

Somewhere in WatchKit Extension you will call something like this: (Swift)

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(["request": "user/pass"], reply: {
    (reply, error) -> Void in
    if reply != nil {
        if let credential = reply["credential"] as? [String: String] {
            let username = credential["username"]
            let password = credential["password"]
        }
    }
})
```

In the iPhone App's AppDelegate, override [`application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:) and do something like this: (Objective-C)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {

    [self beginBackgroundTask];

    if (userInfo != nil && userInfo[@"request"] != nil) {
        NSString *request = userInfo[@"request"];

        if ([request isEqualToString:@"user/pass"]) {
            reply(@{@"username":USERNAME, @"password":PASSWORD});
        }

    }

    [self endBackgroundTask];
}
```

Comment: How would you recommend logging into Parse from the Watch side, instead of passing username and password as you demoed here?